# Loading Google Maps script in Phonegap after the phone gets online

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, loading, offline

I've got a Phonegap app (Late Bars London, Android) which uses Google maps, which require a line to load Google's map scripts similar to:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=......&sensor=true"></script>
```

and then the app draws a map. This works ok if the phone is online when the app is first started but does not if not, until you kill the app and restart it.

I'd like something that would load the script when the phone gets on line, a bit like:

```
function LoadGooglesScript() { 
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=......&sensor=true"></script>; 
GoDrawSomeMaps();
}

document.addEventListener("online", LoadGooglesScript, false);
```

but I know that's the wrong syntax. Any idea to achieve that kind of effect where the script is loaded automatically after the app gets online?

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I seem to have found an answer after a fair bit of mucking around. Basically it is to have two html files, one for starting up and one for the main app. The index.html which starts up looks like:

```
<body>
Loading. If your phone is offline the app will load when you go online. 

<script>
setInterval(function () {
   if (navigator.onLine) { 
    window.location.replace("main.html");}
 }, 250);
</script>
</body>
```

And then the main.html has the main app and the

```
 <script src="...
```

bit.

Actually that still didn't work - I think it redirected before the internet was properly sorted. I got it going better but putting in a 3 sec delay as below:

```
<script>

if (!(navigator.onLine)) {
document.getElementById("map").innerHTML="<center><br><br><br><br><br><h3>I'm afraid this app needs an internet connection to start up</h3><h3>It should start when you get online</h3></center>"
    }
    else window.location.replace("main.html");

setInterval(function () {
   if (navigator.onLine) { 
        document.getElementById("map").innerHTML="<center><br><br><br><br><br><h3>Trying in 3 seconds</h3></center>";
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.replace("main.html");
        }, 3000);
    }
}, 250);

</script>
```